# Nautilus files sidebar occupies more than half of page

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, files

This might be a stupid question but it troubled me for 1 hour and I'm still unable to solve. I accidentally clicked something in nautilus file management after which the sidebar  occupies half of the page. [See attached screenshot] I tried to drag the right boundary of sidebar to make it narrower but it can't be dragged anymore left. How could I reset it to normal? Thanks in advance. 
[sidebar_occupies_half_of_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5zu.png)

Update:
The problem remains even after I upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04. [stuck_in_middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgNzb.gif) 
I'm able to drag the separation bar to the right, however, whenever I try to drag it to the left, it get stuck in the middle (see gif).

Comment: The problem remains even after I reinstall nautilus.

Comment: Seems to be caused by that long file path, which isn't wrapped. Try to give that bookmark a shorter name.

Comment: have you tried purging nautilus and reinstalling? sudo apt purge --auto-remove nautilus then sudo apt install nautilus

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally moved the position of the separation bar. This will be saved in your preferences, therefore will survive a reinstall.

To get you layout back move you mouse to the line separating left from right side until the cursor changes to something like (example shown for 19.04):

[image]

Then click and hold the left mouse button to be able to drag the line to the desired position:

[image]

Release the mouse button if happy. Done.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But as shown in the gif I just took, the separation bar get stuck in the middle whenever I try to drag it to the left.